# selecting top( x ) multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Sorry for the rubbish title but hopefully this will explain:

Given the table

```
 name     |   data
---------------------
   1      |   1000
   1      |   2000
   1      |   3000
   2      |   1500
   2      |   2500
   2      |   3500
```

I want to be able to select the top( x ) for all names ordered by the data value. So if x = 2 the return will be

```
 name     |   data
---------------------
   1      |   2000
   1      |   3000
   2      |   2500
   2      |   3500
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
;with cte AS
(
SELECT name, data, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY data DESC) AS RN
FROM YourTable
)
SELECT name, data
FROM cte 
WHERE RN<=2
ORDER BY name, data
```

Comment: Thanks again for this, used it to cut a 7-8 hour process down to 10-20 minutes

Answer (score 2):

A slightly universal way would be (*had not seen the edited tags that specified sql server*)

```
Select
  name, 
  data 
From
  <table> tbl
Where
  data In
     ( Select Top 2 Distinct
          data 
       From
          <table> 
       Where
          name = tbl.name
       Order By
          data Desc
     )
```